# Problems Importing Scala Libraries In Intellij

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I am trying to import a project into intellij. I am using a java sdk and am trying to import the scala libraries. When I try to run my code I get

```
Warning:scala: skipping Scala files without a Scala SDK in module(s) main
```

When I try to add the scala libray:

```
File>Project Structure>Global Libraries>+>scala-sdk(2.11.7)>Apply
```

I get another error message:

```
Module "lab1"
must not contain source root "C:\Users\Andrew\lab1\src\main\scala".
The root already belongs to module "main"
```

This is my first time using this IDE so I am a bit lost.

Comment: If you go to Project Structure > Modules, you can verify that the sources directories are correctly assigned. Is using sbt an option? Setting up an sbt Scala or mixed Java/Scala project in IntelliJ is super simple.

Comment: Also can you clarify what kind of project you have. Is it a Java project that uses Scala libraries? Or a Scala project?

Comment: It is a scala project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this within the IDE (IntelliJ 2016.2.4) by adding the correct framework support. [See this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/adding-frameworks-support.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by adding "Gradle: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.11" to the "Dependencies" tap of the module:

File -> Project Structure... -> Modules -> (choose Your module) -> Dependencies -> Add (green "+" sign) -> Library... -> Gradle: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.11 -> Add selected -> Apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
Warning:scala: skipping Scala files without a Scala SDK in module(s) main
```

I got that error message and IntelliJ couldn't find the test classes. My problem was a broken dependency that for some reason I missed in IntelliJ.

The root problem was clear when I tried to run gradle from command line eg:

```
gradle test
```

After I got the dependency fixed and the build passing from command line, the problem in IntelliJ was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by simply updating IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

I in my case when I got this warning - it was PyCharm is opened in parallel with Intellij. Once I closed it - everything was ok

Answer (score 0):

Noticed this error after updating Intellij

What worked for me is removing .idea and opening it as a new project